# How to add additional dll search directories for native unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a big code base which has many solutions and many more projects.

When I write unit tests they often depend on a number of dlls being present which are built by other solutions into different output folders to my current solution.

I usually add build steps to copy required dll's to the current solution's output folder so that they can be found when I run unit tests. This can end up in a lot of wasted space and confusion with duplicate dlls and which is the master copy of each dll which is the one that should go into the installer.

Is there a better way of adding additional search directories?

I was considering having a TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE that will AddDllDirectory() and then marking the dll's as delay loaded so that when they do load the added dll directory will be searched. But, I don't think that works as you have to mark the dll's as delay loaded in the exe. But, the exe is the testrunner which is out of my control.

Comment: What approach did you use in the end?

Comment: For Visual Studio tests we stayed with the method of copying dlls output by other solutions into the output directory of the current solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've also exhausted many ideas (delayed loaded dlls, custom test runners, VS environment paths, assembly .runsettings etc.) and am coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: For a lot of new code we've used GTest instead. I find that to be a bit more flexible and reliable, especially when any of the code under test is multithreaded. VsTest only seems to cope with single threaded code.

Answer (score 3):

Your consideration is absolutely right. You can load dependency dlls in VS testrunner context, as sure as a gun,  in this  way:

1) setup your test project to deploy all required dlls into output dir (for example with the help of pre\post-build steps)

2) set delay loading of dlls in test project settings. (Test project-properties-Linker-Input-Delay loaded dlls = enter list of dependency dlls)

3) Setup directory to search dlls. It could be either TEST_MODULE_INITIALIZE or TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE. Simple case is to use SetDllDirectory for this purpose. If you want to use AddDllDirectory - use it [carefully](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If SetDefaultDllDirectories is first called with LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS, directories specified with AddDllDirectory are added to the process DLL search path. Otherwise, directories specified with the AddDllDirectory function are used only for LoadLibraryEx function calls that specify LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS.

Comment: I think the link you wanted is to [AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513(v=vs.85).aspx). Or at least, the text you have quoted comes from there.

Comment: Thank you, @FabioTurati! I have corrected the link.

Comment: Does this imply invoking SetDllDirectory at compile time? Correct me if I'm wrong, but dlls are load-time linked by default, so the host process attempts to load before static initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best method, but since you're using Visual Studio 2013, you should look into test settings to control what is deployed when you run your tests.  Inside of test settings you can specify files or folders in the **Deployment** section which will allow you to select files outside of your current solution.  You can create multiple test settings (one for local and one to use on a build server if the paths to these files are going to be different).

Again, maybe not the best solution, but it has worked for me in the past.

**Specifying Test Settings for Visual Studio Tests** - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx

Comment: There are known issues with native C++ dlls listed on msdn: Assembly and deployment settings not working.